# OEM kernel gets installed seemingly automatically

Tags: 20.04, kernel, oem

We have the weird issue that some Ubuntu notebooks at the company seem to have an OEM kernel installed and active instead of the HWE kernel that we install on top of the regular Ubuntu LTS installation.

The hardware: Dell Latitude 5420
The OEM package: oem-somerville-charmander-14-meta/focal-updates

By default we install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with the HWE kernel on top.
We tried to reproduce this behavior but didn't succeed so far. The 5420 notebooks that we tried had the latest HWE kernel installed (5.13) and not the OEM.

Also, when opening the program "Software & Updates" and navigating to "Additional Drivers" the above mentioned package gets proposed. But apparently, the users did not install it explicitly through that program.

What might be good to know: The ethernet port on these notebook models does not run properly with Ubuntu 20.04 HWE. (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1930754)
Maybe that bug is fixed with the OEM kernel and Ubuntu made it that HWE changes to OEM in  that case?

Can anybody explain that behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IME, on ubuntu linux 5.15 does not work well with this laptop, but 5.14 and 5.17 oem kernels might (they did for me)